# Wanted : Theory for Copy, Move in Nodes in Trees (such as Drag and Drop)

Tags: algorithm, drag-and-drop, tree, move

One of my apps maintains a tree of objects, displayed in an outline view.  I've implemented a long routine for moving or copying object(s) from one node to another.  This routine is invoked, for example, when the user executes a drag and drop in the outline view.

It gets to be fun when objects are moved within the same parent.  Or when objects are not allowed at certain nodes, although I do allow the user to drop them there, I helpfully adjust their final location.  After several weeks, and a few bug fixes during the first few releases, I got this routine to always behave as expected.  I think.  But I'm not sure, because this method was developed *ad hoc*.  That means: When I found something that didn't work, I fixed it.

Currently I'm working on improving its performance in a few corner cases.  For example, code which re-indexes all affected nodes immediately after each any object is moved is logically bullet-proof, but costly when the user moves 1000 items in at the head of a node already containing 1000 items.

As I look at this code, it seems to me that some computer scientist might at some point have written a textbook chapter or something on this topic, and I should buy that book, read it, rip out my *ad hoc* code and do it the *right* way.  But I can't find any in a web search.  Does anyone know of any such book?

Or maybe not.  Maybe this is one of those cases where, after all is said and done, each application too different to propose a general solution?

Thanks,

Jerry Krinock

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it works, which is much more important than if it is the right way.

Are users dragging 1000 items around and having issue with the resultant lag?

If you need a speed up, a good optimization is to decouple moving and indexing and ensure your moving code always indexes after it completes the move. Alternatively you can allow your moving code to take an array of sources and destinations to allow it to only index once, but still control the indexing process.

Most of the algorithms I have seen and experienced are focused on either obtaining data or optimizing your tree (in a case where the exact tree structure isn't important) to improve obtaining data. Since your code has a specific tree structure in mind, they won't really help here.

Comment: Thank you, Guvante.  I guess the answer is that no one has ever written a general solution to this problem; maybe it's not possible.  So I just completed my performance tweaks, like you said.  Instead of re-indexing as each item is added, entering each added index into a dictionary of index sets, one index set for each parent, then "restacking" the children, of each dictionary after all was done.

Comment: @Jarry. Of course poeple have written this before, it's too common a problem. I'm in the same process now, that's how I found this post. But it gets ugly when you drag an entire tree onto a tree node in a group etc. Care to share your code?

Comment: Sorry Jan, I didn't see your request until now.  Here is my code…  https://gist.github.com/jerrykrinock/7794404